# Running asp.net application for the first time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm beginner in asp.net i just create a empty web-application  and after that i create a controller but it is showing the error.

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0

here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class Welcome : Controller
    {
        // GET: Welcome

        public string Index()
        {
            return "Hello World, this is ASP.Net MVC Tutorials";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Default controller is home and action index. So you won't have a page unless you have home controller with an index

Comment: Can you post your route config?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to rename your Welcome-Class to HomeController or change the default route in your App_Start/RouteConfig.cs to point to Welcome by default:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Welcome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

As a side note, you should name your controller "WelcomeController", not "Welcome".

Comment: Do you have a MVC project and are missing a Views/Welcome/Index.cshtml view?

Comment: no i'm simply return the string as you can see and it is in controller and project is almost empty it consist only the welcome controller

Comment: So you used the empty template? I unfortunately have no experience with this one, but I'd recommend using the WebAPI-template if you want to do something like that, it offers a good starting point and already has a default route and controller you just need to change.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend attribute routing.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

```
[Route(“api/welcome”)]
```

Can be added to your actions to specify the route with the action.

Answer (score 0):

Either you make a change of the default controller from 'Home' to 'Welcome' in your route like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Welcome", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
```

Or your can simply go to the following url in your browser:

```
http://localhost:58470/Welcome
```

Change the port from 58470 to your application one.

Comment: try the both of them and still have the problem

Comment: you should change your dot net version to .net core 2.0 and then try once again.